# Automatic pin placement with Layout XL in Cadence Virtuoso?

Tags: layout, cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I have a big mixed signal design, with 363 pins. Layout XL knows the position of the pins (green line connects each pin with its correct position while I'm dragging it around).

My question is: how can I avoid spending one week doing such a tedious activity and make pins placement automatic? I have always done it manually, but this time the design is too big. There MUST be a way to run a script, or issue a command from some menu, to save time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Layout XL, navigate to Connectivity/Update/Components And Nets. Click on the I/O pins tab and select all the pins you wish to have auto placed.  Define the layers for pins and labels that you desire and click update at the bottom right of the "Specify Pins to be Generated" tab.  Click OK.

The pins you just generated will appear around the origin of the layout.  To auto place them according to the instances in your schematic, navigate to Place/Analog/Adjust Cell Pins.

Comment: Thank you so much Daron!

I did it manually in the end, but I will give your solution a try in case I face this issue again.

Maybe also other visitors will find your answer helpful.

Many thanks again!